# Determine which plugin is overriding key bindings

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7. In Key Bindings - default:

```
{ "keys": ["f9"], "command": "sort_lines", "args": {"case_sensitive": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f9"], "command": "sort_lines", "args": {"case_sensitive": true} },
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> works, but <kbd>f9</kbd> doesn't, and it is not overridden in my Key Bindings - User. I have a number of  plugins. How can I determine which plugin is causing this issue? I'm not asking which plugin it is, by the way, I'm asking how to determine which plugin it is.

It shouldn't matter, but here's a list of the plugins I have:

- AdvancedNewFile
- AllAutocomplete
- FilterLines
- GitGutter
- PackageControl
- ProjectManager
- RubyDebugger
- SidebarEnhancements
- SublimeBookmarks
- SublimeREPL

Comment: Are you on OS X, where the F keys have special behavior associated with them?

Comment: No, updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) plugin to identify key collisions in Sublime.